# How to get isZoomed from underlaying dygraphs when using ng-dygraphs?

Tags: javascript, angular, frontend, dygraphs

Ng-dygraphs is a library that uses Dygraphs library and is prepared for Angular usage. Dygraphs has a property called isZoomed. How to access this property when using NG-dygraphs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
@ViewChild('ngDygraphs') ngDygraphs : ElementRef;


<ng-dygraphs
  #ngDygraphs
  [data]="data"
  [options]="options">
</ng-dygraphs>
```

and make `console.log(this.ngDygraphs)` for ngDygraphs and get its attributes.
There will be `isZoomed` property

Comment: I used drawCallback to fetch dygraph object and store into variable, and then fetch isZoomed from it. But i like your solution. Didn't test it, but it looks nice